Azure AI Search Split skillset configuration
I have a json array stored in a json file. The array elements have following fields:- id, name, category, description, etc. Description fields might have large content (100k+ chars) so I want to do the chunking of this field. Keeping max 5000 chars and page overlap too so that chunks are related to each other. Currently I have created index by importing the dataset and setting parsing mode to json array, so my index has all the array element fields as the index fields. Let me know how can I chunk the description field using split skillset in Azure AI Search.

have you tried any approach? if yes add those details. please check the azure ai search docs.

Yes I tried to configure text split skillset in my indexer.

Check below solution. if any error/blockers facing add those details.

Here is the Text split skill you can use to chunk the documents.
Go to skillset tab and create new skillset with below kind of definition.
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
    "textSplitMode" : "pages", 
    "maximumPageLength": 5000,
    "pageOverlapLength": 100,
    "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/<Description_field>"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "textItems",
            "targetName": "mypages"
        }
    ]
}

Here, maximumPageLength 5000 characters is given , pageOverlapLength of 100 characters and you get the output in document/mypages.
Next, create new field in your index which is of type array of strings and add the output field mappings like below.
"outputFieldMappings": [
  {
    "sourceFieldName": "document/mypages",
    "targetFieldName": "field_your_created_for_chunked_docs",
    "mappingFunction": null
  }
],

This will give you the results in the field you created.
Check how the indexing works in each stage here.

in indexer you need to do output field mappings. please check the docs.

how you are passing the description to chat completion?
